# how to allocate memory to a struct that contains a dynamic array? (C)

Tags: arrays, memory, dynamic, struct, malloc

I am not quite clear on how to allocate memory to a struct pointer that contains a dynamic array field. for example, I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct log_file {
    char *name;
    int updatesize;
    int numupdates;
    int *users;  /* dynamic array of integers */
} log_data;
```

When I created a pointer of `log_data` using: `log_data *log_ptr = malloc(sizeof(log_data));`

How do I allocate enough memory for the dynamic array `users` in the struct?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
log_ptr->users = malloc(sizeof(int)*numOfUsers);
```

Or if you want to keep it independent of the type of `*users`:

```
log_ptr->users = malloc(sizeof(*log_ptr->users)*numOfUsers);
```